# Program inserting an element in single linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node* insert_beg(struct node *h,int x)
{
    struct node *t;
    printf("\n address = %u --- ",*h);
    t=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(h==NULL)
    {
        t->data=x;
        t->next=NULL;
        h=t;
    }
    else
    {


        t->data=x;
        t->next=h;
        h=t;
    }
    return h;

}
void display(struct node *h1)
{
    struct node *t=h1;
    while(t->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",t->data);
        t=t->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct node *p=NULL;
    int a,ch=5;
    while(ch--)
    {

    printf("\n Enter data");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    p=insert_beg(p,a);
    display(p);
    }display(p);

}
```

The above is a code for inserting element in the begining of the single linked link list in c.

The code compiles successfuly but when i am trying to insert an element the system hangs up... Not to locate the error. Can anyone suggest the correction i need to done.

Is there any error in the  expression mentioned below... Need help.

```
p=insert_beg(p,a);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "[i]s there any error in the expression mentioned below"? Do you mean that you get a build error on that line? Or do you mean you get a crash when you run the program? Or do you simply wonder if the line is correct (without actually building/running your program)? Please elaborate. If you get a crash at runtime, have you tried running a debug build in a debugger, to catch the crash in action and locate where it actually happens in your code?

Comment: delete `printf("\n address = %u --- ",*h);` Also at `display` :  `while(t->next!=NULL)` --> `while(t != NULL)`

Comment: don't forget to free memory for the Node, I can see memory freak there in main()

Comment: If you want to print the address of the node you passed to your insert function, use the `%p` specifier instead of `%u` in your `printf()`, and *don't* dereference `h` (which is `NULL` for the first insert). In other words, print the value of the pointer (which is the address of the node if there is one), not the value of what it points to.

Comment: `printf("\n address = %u --- ",*h);` attempts to dereference a `NULL` pointer.  Try `printf("\n address = %p --- ", (void *) h);`

Comment: Actually i get a crash when i run the program. It is showing "Window is looking for the problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while(t->next!=NULL)
```

should be:

```
    while(t!=NULL)
```

also, your insert function can be simplified to:

```
struct node* insert_beg(struct node *h,int x)
{
    struct node *t;
    t=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    t->data=x;
    t->next=h;
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node* insert_beg(struct node *h,int x)
{
    struct node *t;
    t=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(h==NULL)
    {
        t->data=x;
        t->next=NULL;
        h=t;
    }
    else
    {
        t->data=x;
        t->next=h;
        h=t;
    }
    return h;
}
void display(struct node *h1)
{
     struct node *t=h1;
     while(t->next!=NULL)
     {
         printf("%d->",t->data);
         t=t->next;
     }
    printf("%d",t->data);
}
int main()
{
    struct node *p=NULL;
    int a,ch=5;
    while(ch>=0)
    {
        printf("\n Enter data:-");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        p=insert_beg(p,a);
        display(p);
        ch--;
    }
    display(p);
```

}

Comment: I needed this code in my program. Helped me where I was stuck. Thanks for the help

Comment: where did you strucked @Pankti

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in:

```
printf("\n address = %u --- ",*h);
```

Trying to print an entire structure.

In general use a debbuger for this as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271363/line-by-line-c-c-code-debugging-in-linux-ubuntu)

You can compile your program with debug information as follows:

```
gcc -o main -g main.c
```

And run it in gdb:

```
gdb main
```

Type 'run' command inside gdb, if it fails you can use a 'backtrace' to get loads of information why. Get comfortable with gdb tutorials as the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) might scare you off at first.

Comment: I had dereference h which was initially assigned NULL value.